# Deleting original image once the image url is updated

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase and as you can see in the code I am updating the user's image url that is stored on the user table.  Is there a way to delete the old image file that's still being stored in my storage bucket once an image is updated?

```
exports.uploadImage = (req, res) => {
  const BusBoy = require("busboy")
  const path = require("path")
  const os = require("os")
  const fs = require("fs")

  const busboy = new BusBoy({ headers: req.headers })

  let imageToBeUploaded = {}
  let imageFileName

  busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    if (mimetype !== `image/jpeg` && mimetype !== `image/png`) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: `Not an acceptable file type` })
    }

    // my.image.png => ['my', 'image', 'png']
    const imageExtension = filename.split(".")[filename.split(".").length - 1]
    // 32756238461724837.png
    imageFileName = `${Math.round(
      Math.random() * 1000000000000
    ).toString()}.${imageExtension}`
    const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), imageFileName)
    imageToBeUploaded = { filepath, mimetype }
    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath))
  })

  busboy.on("finish", () => {
    admin
      .storage()
      .bucket(config.storageBucket)
      .upload(imageToBeUploaded.filepath, {
        resumable: false,
        metadata: {
          metadata: {
            contentType: imageToBeUploaded.mimetype
          }
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        const imageUrl = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${config.storageBucket}/o/${imageFileName}?alt=media`
        return db.doc(`/users/${req.user.uid}`).update({ imageUrl })
      })
      .then(() => {
        return res.json({ message: "image uploaded successfully" })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
        return res.status(500).json({ error: "something went wrong" })
      })
  })
  busboy.end(req.rawBody)
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for you to achieve that is by using a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing#functions-writing-helloworld-http-nodejs) to be run, once you have a new upload of photo done on your function.

I would recommend you to take a look at the article [Automatically delete your Firebase Storage Files from Firestore with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/automatically-delete-your-firebase-storage-files-from-firestore-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase-36542c39ba0d), to get more information, on how to perform these automatic deletions with Cloud Functions. Besides that, on this post from the Community [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635498/how-to-delete-a-file-using-cloud-functions), you can check that with node.js language.

On these other two posts from the Community, you can get more ideas and insights to achieve this goal.

- [Firebase function (written in NodeJS) to delete file from Cloud Storage when an object is removed from Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356384/firebase-function-written-in-nodejs-to-delete-file-from-cloud-storage-when-an)
- [Firebase Storage-How to delete file from storage with node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54089533/firebase-storage-how-to-delete-file-from-storage-with-node-js)

Let me know if the information helped you!